# sqoop and password encryption using password-file option

Tags: sqoop

I'm using sqoop-1.4.3-cdh4.6.0.jar and i'm wondering if the --password-file option is avialable in that version.
If yes, can someone give me an example of how the encryption process would be invoked?  provide a command example ,  i can see that the patch has been introduced with cdh4.6.0 but not sure if sqoop 1.4.3 can use it.

Answer (score 5):

Chances are it's not in CDH 4.6.0 given https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-1223. I'd upgrade to Sqoop 1.4.5 to get this functionality.

Here's a quick Sqoop command example:

```
sqoop import \
    -Dorg.apache.sqoop.credentials.loader.class=org.apache.sqoop.util.password.CryptoFileLoader \
    -Dorg.apache.sqoop.credentials.loader.crypto.passphrase=sqoop2 \
    --connect jdbc:mysql://example.com/sqoop \
    --username sqoop \
    --password-file file:///tmp/pass.enc \
    --table tbl
```

The important parameters to note are:

1. org.apache.sqoop.credentials.loader.class - Credentials loader
2. org.apache.sqoop.credentials.loader.crypto.alg – The Algorithm used to decrypt the file (default is AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding).
3. org.apache.sqoop.credentials.loader.crypto.salt – The salt used to derive a key with the passphrase (default is SALT).
4. org.apache.sqoop.credentials.loader.crypto.iterations – Number of PBKDF2 iterations (default is 10000).
5. org.apache.sqoop.credentials.loader.crypto.salt.key.len – Derived key length (default is 128).
6. org.apache.sqoop.credentials.loader.crypto.passphrase Passphrase used to derive key.

There are several other options available to you as well [more](http://ingest.tips/2015/03/12/managing-passwords-sqoop/).

Comment: How do you make  the pass.enc?