# How to protect password and username in Sqoop?

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I want to hide my password that I am using to import data from my RDBMS to Hadoop cluster. I am using `--option-files` for keeping my password and username in a text file but it's not protected.

Can I do some kind encryption on that particular file for better protection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Secure way of supplying password to the database.

> You should save the password in a file on the users home directory with 400 permissions and specify the path to that file using the `--password-file` argument, and is the preferred method of entering credentials. Sqoop will then read the password from the file and pass it to the MapReduce cluster using secure means with out exposing the password in the job configuration. The file containing the password can either be on the Local FS or HDFS. For example:

```
$ sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://database.example.com/employees \
--username venkatesh --password-file ${user.home}/.password
```

Check drill [docs](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_connecting_to_a_database_server) for more details.

Also, you can use `-P` option to **Read password from console**.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that this question has been addressed previously [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29108370/1651940),
also described on this [hortonworks page](https://community.hortonworks.com/answers/13790/view.html) and basically consists on creating and .enc file. You also need to configure several parameters like the key to reveal the encryption.

```
sqoop import \
-Dorg.apache.sqoop.credentials.loader.class=org.apache.sqoop.util.password.CryptoFileLoader \
-Dorg.apache.sqoop.credentials.loader.crypto.passphrase=sqoop2 \
--connect jdbc:mysql://example.com/sqoop \
--username sqoop \
--password-file file:///tmp/pass.enc \
--table tbl
```

Here are multiple parameters that can be configured (again following the reference):

- org.apache.sqoop.credentials.loader.class - Credentials loader
- org.apache.sqoop.credentials.loader.crypto.alg – The Algorithm used to decrypt the file (default is AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding).
- org.apache.sqoop.credentials.loader.crypto.salt – The salt used to derive a key with the passphrase (default is SALT).
- org.apache.sqoop.credentials.loader.crypto.iterations – Number of PBKDF2 iterations (default is 10000).
- org.apache.sqoop.credentials.loader.crypto.salt.key.len – Derived key length (default is 128).
- org.apache.sqoop.credentials.loader.crypto.passphrase Passphrase used to derive key.

Alternatively you can also follow [Sqoop documentation page](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_saved_jobs_and_passwords) and create a password alias that gets retrieved with an implementation of `CredentialProviderPasswordLoader` class. You can see the whole class [here](https://apache.googlesource.com/sqoop/+/refs/heads/trunk/src/java/org/apache/sqoop/util/password/CredentialProviderPasswordLoader.java)